# g++ fails to link to libmysqlclient

Tags: virtualbox, mysql, macosx, g++, ld

I use Ubuntu 12.04 on a virtual machine on my MacbookPro. I installed build-essential, mysql-server and libmysqlclient-dev. Both commands 'mysql' and 'mysql_config' work.

However, the following program does not link:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    printf("hello world\n");

    //init
        {
        MYSQL itsmysql;

        MYSQL* mytemp=0; mytemp=mysql_init(&itsmysql);
        if(mytemp){
            printf("hello world YEP\n");
            }
        else{   
            printf("hello world NOOOO\n");
            }
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

I run g++ with the command:

```
g++ `mysql_config --cflags` `mysql_config --libs` test.cpp
```

I had this running under a 32 bit version of Ubuntu, but now I have a 64 bits version. The problem occurs both using VirtualBox as with Parallels. The output of 'mysql_config' looks ok.

It seems to me that the linker cannot find the appropriate file/architecture type amongst the libmysqlclient files.

What should I try next?

The error message is 'undefined reference to mysql_init'.

Comment: Ah, sorry, just added it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead: worked for me

```
g++ -o test test.cpp `mysql_config --cflags` `mysql_config --libs`
```

Then test

```
./test
Hello world YEP
```

Comment: g++ test.cpp `mysql_config --cflags` `mysql_config --libs`

Comment: apparently the mysql_config stuff needs to be at the end of the line :-)

Comment: Posting "thanks" is not the preferred way of showing appreciation on this site.  You can vote up answers you like if it's your question or anywhere once you have 15 reputation.  You can also click the tick symbol next to the answer if it's your question, as it is here, to say you have accepted it.

Comment: Well i clicked, i will not 'thank you' again:-)